# How to replicate an element in Spark dataframe in Scala?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe

Suppose I have a DataFrame:

```
val testDf = sc.parallelize(Seq(
  (1,2,"x", Array(1,2,3,4)))).toDF("one", "two", "X", "Array")

+---+---+---+------------+
|one|two|  X|       Array|
+---+---+---+------------+
|  1|  2|  x|[1, 2, 3, 4]|
+---+---+---+------------+
```

I want to replicate the single elements, let's say 4 times, in order to achieve a single row DataFrame with each field as an array of four elements. The desired output would be:

```
+------------+------------+------------+------------+
|         one|         two|           X|       Array|
+------------+------------+------------+------------+
|[1, 1, 1, 1]|[2, 2, 2, 2]|[x, x, x, x]|[1, 2, 3, 4]|
+------------+------------+------------+------------+
```

Comment: can the size of the Array differ between rows or is it constant?

Comment: The size is constant in my case.

Comment: cool, but why???

Comment: Because in this case I will be able to explode my dataframe's each column and I will have a new dataframe with 4 rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use builit-in `array` function to replicate `n` time column of your choice.

Below is PoC code.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
val replicate = (n: Int, colName: String) => array((1 to n).map(s => col(colName)):_*)
val replicatedCol = Seq("one", "two", "X").map(s => replicate(4, s).as(s))
val cols = col("Array") +: replicatedCol
val testDf = sc.parallelize(Seq(
    (1,2,"x", Array(1,2,3,4)))).toDF("one", "two", "X", "Array").select(cols:_*)
testDf.show(false)

+------------+------------+------------+------------+
|Array       |one         |two         |X           |
+------------+------------+------------+------------+
|[1, 2, 3, 4]|[1, 1, 1, 1]|[2, 2, 2, 2]|[x, x, x, x]|
+------------+------------+------------+------------+
```

In the case, you want different `n` for each column

```
val testDf = sc.parallelize(Seq(
  (1,2,"x", Array(1,2,3,4)))).toDF("one", "two", "X", "Array").select(replicate(2, "one").as("one"), replicate(3, "X").as("X"), replicate(4, "two").as("two"), $"Array")
  testDf.show(false)

+------+---------+------------+------------+
|one   |X        |two         |Array       |
+------+---------+------------+------------+
|[1, 1]|[x, x, x]|[2, 2, 2, 2]|[1, 2, 3, 4]|
+------+---------+------------+------------+
```

Comment: I think `n` is not the same for all rows

Comment: @RaphaelRoth You can call `replicate` manually with `n` of your choice. I updated my answer.

Comment: @cue Your solution is not working for me, I get an `java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException` error. Idon't understand the logic behind `.map(s => col(colName)):_*)`

Comment: @sanyi14ka I think your copy/paste mistake, the code works fine for me. And actually it's `array( (1 to n).map(s => col(colName)):_* )`, if you look at `array` signature: `array(cols*)`

Comment: Actually, the `.as(s)` gives me the error. I don't know why, maybe I'm using an older version of Spark (1.6.0) . I have no idea, but if I take that part out, then your solution is working fine, I just have to rename the column names. With your method I was able to solve my use case, so I accepted your answer!

Answer (score 1):

Well, here is my solution:

First declare the columns you want to replicate:

```
val columnsToReplicate =  List("one", "two", "X")
```

Then define the replication factor and the udf to perform it:

```
val replicationFactor = 4
val replicate = (s:String) => {
  for {
    i <- 1 to replicationFactor
      } yield s
  }

val replicateudf = functions.udf(replicate)
```

Then just perform the foldLeft on the `DataFrame` when the columname belongs to your list of desired column names:

```
testDf.columns.foldLeft(testDf)((acc, colname) => if (columnsToReplicate.contains(colname)) acc.withColumn(colname, replicateudf(acc.col(colname))) else acc)
```

Output:

```
+------------+------------+------------+------------+
|         one|         two|           X|       Array|
+------------+------------+------------+------------+
|[1, 1, 1, 1]|[2, 2, 2, 2]|[x, x, x, x]|[1, 2, 3, 4]|
+------------+------------+------------+------------+
```

Note: You need to import this class:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions
```

**EDIT:**

Variable replicationFactor as suggested in comments:

```
val mapColumnsToReplicate =  Map("one"->4, "two"->5, "X"->6)

val replicateudf2 = functions.udf ((s: String, replicationFactor: Int) =>

    for {
      i <- 1 to replicationFactor
    } yield s
  )

testDf.columns.foldLeft(testDf)((acc, colname) => if (mapColumnsToReplicate.keys.toList.contains(colname)) acc.withColumn(colname, replicateudf2($"$colname", functions.lit(mapColumnsToReplicate(colname))))` else acc)
```

Output with those values above:

```
+------------+---------------+------------------+------------+
|         one|            two|                 X|       Array|
+------------+---------------+------------------+------------+
|[1, 1, 1, 1]|[2, 2, 2, 2, 2]|[x, x, x, x, x, x]|[1, 2, 3, 4]|
+------------+---------------+------------------+------------+
```

Comment: `one` and `two` are `int` type.

Comment: It's working for me in the spark-shell, i guess an implicit toString is being performed

Comment: this only works if the replication factor is constant

Comment: Right, If not, you can always turn your columnsToBeReplicated List into a map with the desired replication factor and get it from there

Comment: @SCouto Your solution works great, however, my problem is that it's hard-coded. Suppose I have 100 columns, which contains 40 columns as ArrayType. And I can't always set the columns which I want to replicate. Do you know  a method to achieve this?

Comment: Will be easy to do in the other way around? I mean, setting the list with the excluded fields and then reversing the if and else clauses in the if?  

Other option will be if you only need to apply this to columns matching some pattern. So you can match it with startsWith or something similar.  


If you want to do that with all the columns will be easy, but if you want it for some columns only I cannot think on anything better

Answer (score 0):

You can use `explode` und `groupBy`/`collect_list` :

```
val testDf = sc.parallelize(
  Seq((1, 2, "x", Array(1, 2, 3, 4)),
    (3, 4, "y", Array(1, 2, 3)),
    (5,6, "z", Array(1)))
).toDF("one", "two", "X", "Array")

testDf
 .withColumn("id",monotonically_increasing_id())
 .withColumn("tmp", explode($"Array"))
 .groupBy($"id")
 .agg(
   collect_list($"one").as("cl_one"),
   collect_list($"two").as("cl_two"),
   collect_list($"X").as("cl_X"),
   first($"Array").as("Array")
)
.select(
   $"cl_one".as("one"),
   $"cl_two".as("two"),
   $"cl_X".as("X"),
   $"Array"
 )
.show()

+------------+------------+------------+------------+
|         one|         two|           X|       Array|
+------------+------------+------------+------------+
|         [5]|         [6]|         [z]|         [1]|
|[1, 1, 1, 1]|[2, 2, 2, 2]|[x, x, x, x]|[1, 2, 3, 4]|
|   [3, 3, 3]|   [4, 4, 4]|   [y, y, y]|   [1, 2, 3]|
+------------+------------+------------+------------+
```

This solution has the advantage that it does not rely on constant array-sizes